# How to connect outlet from storyboard to UITableViewCell class Xcode 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, xcode11

How can we connect outlet with the table view custom cell class in storyboard? As in earlier Xcodes, there is a button to open two windows in storyboard screen but in new Xcode that button is missing. Please guide how to achieve that functionality.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click here (1), and then select the file in the right panel that appears (2), step 1 and 2 in the image, then you can connect outlet as always ;)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## Here you have how to open the tab to drag the outlets from the view to the viewController in Xcode11

[image: Here you have how to open the tab to drag the outlets]

---

---

## Here you have the result

[image: Here you have the result]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also hold the option button and left-click on the file you want to open, that way, it manually opens. This is for Xcode 11

Answer (score 0):

For me, the clean-and-build did not work, but the restart-of-xcode did the trick.